# Why is my f string related index not working?

Tags: python, web-scraping, indexing, beautifulsoup, formatting

I'm new to programming and I'm struggling with webscraping in python. I'm using beautiful soup to scrape a website for a personal project related to Apex Legends. I want to have a script that just tells me the current map in rotation. My problem is that I am returned the wrong time zone and want to change it so the output matches my time. Here it the entire code involved.

I want to know what I am doing wrong. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated. If there is an easier way to get the correct Time Zone from using bs4 that would help too.

```
import requests # scrapes html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # parses the webpage

# lists to store info
maps = []
times = []

# scrape the webpage
URL = "https://apexlegendsstatus.com/current-map/battle_royale/pubs"
page = requests.get(URL)

# parse the content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

# locate the current map text order
for i in soup.find_all('h3'):
    map_data = i.text
    maps.append(map_data)

# locate the times related to current map order
for i in soup.find_all('p'):
    time_data = i.text
    times.append(time_data)
  
# removes irrelevant indexes
times.pop(0)
times.pop(-1)
times.pop(-1)

# fix the time zones cause the bot doesnt do that. also fixes 1 formatting
for i in range(len(times)):
  if (f"{i}:") in times[i]:
    times[i] = times[i].replace((f"{i}:"), (f"{i+4}:"))

  if "starts in 1 hours" in times[i]:
      times[i] = times[i].replace("starts in 1 hours", "starts in 1 hour")

# prints the next 3 at corresponding indexes
ind = 0 
while ind < 3:
    print(f"\n{maps[ind]}")
    print(f"{times[ind]}\n")
    ind += 1
```

This is where the problem (I believe) lies. When I have the semicolons in the f strings, the IF statement does NOT go through. When I removed the semicolons, it worked. The problem with it working here is that it now replaces all numbers and not just the hours that I need to be fixed. I have no idea why this is happening.

```
# fix the time zones cause the bot doesnt do that. also fixes 1 formatting
for i in range(len(times)):
  if (f"{i}:") in times[i]:
    times[i] = times[i].replace((f"{i}:"), (f"{i+4}:"))
```

I also had this code below initially, however, I wanted to go for something better. The below code worked correctly, it was just ugly.

```
# fix the time zones cause the bot doesnt do that. also fixes 1 formatting
# did it this way cause its in a string, probably a more efficient way
for i in range(len(times)):
    if "00" in times[i]:
        times[i] = times[i].replace("00:", "08:")
    if "01" in times[i]:
        times[i] = times[i].replace("01:", "09:")
    if "02" in times[i]:
        times[i] = times[i].replace("02:", "10:")
    if "03" in times[i]:
        times[i] = times[i].replace("03:", "11:")
    if "04" in times[i]:
        times[i] = times[i].replace("04:", "12:")
    if "05" in times[i]:
        times[i] = times[i].replace("05:", "01:")
    if "06" in times[i]:
        times[i] = times[i].replace("06:", "02:")
    if "07" in times[i]:
        times[i] = times[i].replace("07:", "03:")
    if "08" in times[i]:
        times[i] = times[i].replace("08:", "04:")
    if "09" in times[i]:
        times[i] = times[i].replace("09:", "05:")
    if "10" in times[i]:
        times[i] = times[i].replace("10:", "06:")
    if "11" in times[i]:
        times[i] = times[i].replace("11:", "07:")
    if "starts in 1 hours" in times[i]:
        times[i] = times[i].replace("starts in 1 hours", "starts in 1 hour")
```

Comment: The `if` shouldn't be necessary because if `(f"{i}:") in times[i]` is false, the following `replace` call with the same substring to replace wouldn't modify `times[i]` as the substring isn't present.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean? I changed it to this but it didn't work. Is this not what you meant?

`for i in range(len(times)):
  times[i] = times[i].replace((f"{i}:"), (f"{i+4}:"))`

The reason I had the if was to look for the hour time I wanted to update.

Answer (score 0):

Your middle snippet doesn't have the same behaviour as your last snippet. The middle snippet uses `i` for two jobs instead of the one that you really want.

You need another variable to iterate over the `0` to `11` of the hours:

```py
for i in range(len(times)):
    for h in range(12):
        digits = f'{h:02}'
        if digits in times[i]:
            replacement_h = ((h + 7) % 12) + 1
            replacement_digits = f'{replacement_h:02}:'
            times[i] = times[i].replace(digits + ":", replacement_digits)
```

The complicated expression `((h + 7) % 12) + 1` should create the `8,9,10,11,12,1 ...` sequence that you need.

Comment: I do have one question for clarification. Where you did you get the replacement formula from? How did you come up with that?

Comment: I'm a programmer. I looked at your working code and realised that `0` maps to `8`, `1` maps to `9`, etc, but `4` maps to `12` and then `5` maps to `1`. So, naively, I just need `h+8`, however, it needs to wrap around, so a modulus operation is needed. There are `12` cases, so it needs to be `% 12`, but the result would be `0` .. `11`, so I need a `+1` on the outside, so the inner part needs to be one less, so `h+7`.

Comment: I had to change the 12 to a 24 since its in military time. Also hen Increased the number of outputs from 3 to 6, the program broke.

Storm Point
From 03:30 to 04:30, ends in 31 mins ---

Broken Moon
From 04:30 to 05:30, starts in 31 mins ---

Olympus
From 05:30 to 07:00, starts in 1 hour, 31 mins ---

Storm Point
From 07:00 to 04:30, starts in 3 hours, 1 mins ---

Broken Moon
From 04:30 to 06:00, starts in 4 hours, 31 mins ---

Olympus
From 06:00 to 07:00, starts in 6 hours, 1 mins ---

Why is it going from 7 to 4:30, the olympus where it says 6 to 7 should be from 10 to 11